# Qmake и определение debug/release

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте. Собираю динамически подключаемую библиотеку в QtCreator, после сборки нужно переместить файлы `.а` и `.dll/.so` в папку `build/[платформа]`(находится в папке проекта). Путь к проекту я беру через `$$PWD`, места, где собираем - `$$OUT_PWD`. Для копирования использую этап сборки `make install`. Проблема такая: как определить, какую версию мы собираем?

Пробовал так:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    TARGET = LPSEngined
    TYPE = debug
} else {
    TARGET = LPSEngine
    TYPE = release
}
```

Если выводить `TYPE` с помощью `message`, то вывод для `debug`-версии будет таким:

`debug
debug
release`

Никакого копирования не происходит(происходит, если собирать только `debug` версию и после сборки снова нажать `CTRL-B`).

Т.к. папки сборки имеют имена `(projectname)-(debug|release)`, то я попробовал следующим образом:

```
eval(_DIR = $$replace(OUT_PWD, -, ' ')) {
     contains(_DIR, Release) {
         TARGET = LPSEngine
         TYPE = release
     } else {
         TARGET = LPSEngined
         TYPE = debug
     }
}
```

Вывод `TYPE` для этого варианта для той же `debug`-версии:

`debug
debug
debug`

Но в этом случае, почему-то не создается цель `install` в `Makefile`(точнее она пустая).

Помогите решить эту проблему.

P.S.: Использую Qt 5.1 beta, Windows 7 x64, QtCreator 2.7, qmake 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! Не знаю правильно ли это - но я делаю так:

```
CONFIG += debug_and_release
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    TARGET = LPSEngined
    MOC_DIR     = tmp/debug_shared/moc
    OBJECTS_DIR = tmp/debug_shared/obj 
} else {
    TARGET = LPSEngine
    MOC_DIR     = tmp/release_shared/moc
    OBJECTS_DIR = tmp/release_shared/obj
}

TEMPLATE    = lib

DESTDIR     = ../libs
DLLDESTDIR  = ../bin

INCLUDEPATH = . include
```

При этом все (*.a) копируются в DLLDESTDIR, (*.dll) в DESTDIR.